# spyder didnt run update file

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder

I am correctly working with python 2.7 and spyder.

I run my code multiple times to check and debug, but every change I do, I have to run spyder 3 times until I can see that change in the outcome.

For example:

Short code: `print "hi"`

And then run it, 
python will print "hi".

Then I change it to `print "hello"` and I run it, python still prints "hi" for around the next 2-3 times until it finally prints "hello".

Of course this problem happens with longer and much complex code, and it has become a problem to know whether spyder runs the correct code or the old version.

Comment: Sounds very weird. Try to delete Spyder and Anaconda, and download the upgraded virsion (anaconda 3), to get python 3.6.
I had some problems, and when i upgraded they disappeared.

Comment: Please run these commands before running your code: 1. `%load_ext autoreload`; 2. `%autoreload 2`. That should fix your problem.