# pyder could not detect the new changed code when it run

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I install the newest version of anaconda (2019.03),update all the pakege today (2019.06.25). But, the spyder always could not detect my new edited code when it run. Everytime I edited my code, even for a one sentense, I need to close the spyder and open it again. It just could not run my new code and always run the old code.

[Spyder does not run new changes in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524514/spyder-does-not-run-new-changes-in-code)
[spyder didnt run update file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662854/spyder-didnt-run-update-file)

Same problems as the above link,but those methods did not work for me.

@Carlos Cordoba, could you help to see how could I deal with this problem? Thanks~!

Comment: There is no code, no error messages, and in general, no way to reproduce the problem based on your description.

Answer (score -2):

change the directory of .py that you are working on.
Right click to sample.py(which is above of console) and choose set console working directory.
You can apply it for each .py while working on it

Comment: This does not appear to be related to the actual question

Comment: ' It just could not run my new code and always run the old code.' he said that . It is the same one which I faced.I changed the directory of it ( a new folder can be ) and uploaded documents in it then it is fixed